# condicion en base a registro en mysql

Tags: php, mysql, condiciones

Buen dia

Les comparto el siguiente codigo que es para mostrar mis registros de mysql en una datatable
Mi pregunta es como logro implementar la condicion if/else para la columna `TC_Estado_eq` la cual solo contine registro `AC` y `IN` los cuales significan Activo e Inactivo.

Lo que quiero con la condicion es que dependiendo el valor que se encuentre la columna `TC_Estado_eq` me lo cambie a Activo o inactivo. Pero hasta el momento con el codigo que tengo solo me muestra en todos Activo aunque algunos tengan IN

```
 while ($data2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2)) { 
           
              echo "<tr>
                      <td width='80' class='center'>$data2[TC_IdEquipo_eq]</td>
                      <td width='80' class='center'>$data2[TC_NumEquipo_eq]</td>
                      <td width='80' class='center'>$data2[TC_NombreTipo_te]</td>
                      <td width='80' class='center'>$data2[TC_NombreMarca_me]</td>
                      <td width='80' class='center'>$data2[TC_Modelo_eq]</td>
                      <td width='80' class='center'>$data2[TC_Serie_eq]</td>
                      <td width='80' class='center'>$data2[TC_NombrePertenencia_pe]</td>
                      <td width='80' class='center'>$data2[TC_NombreArea_ar]</td>
                      <td width='80' class='center'>$data2[TC_Opcion_tc]</td>
                      <td width='80' class='center'>$data2[TC_Estado_eq]</td>";

                      
                      $datos = $data2['TC_Estado_eq'];

                      if($datos = "AC") {
                        echo '<td width=80 class=center><font color="#FF0000">Activo</font></td>';
                      
                      } else{
                        echo '<td width=80 class=center><Font color="#FF8C00">Inactivo</FONT></td>';
                     }

                    echo "</tr>";
                  }
            ?>
```

Anexo imagen de mi datatable
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De antemano gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Porque en el `if` haces una [**asignación**](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.assignment.php) al poner un sólo signo de `=`, pon dos, o tres, si quieres comparación estricta.

```
if($datos == "AC") {
```

O bien:

```
if($datos === "AC") {
```

Para más detalles, revisa el apartado [*Operadores de comparación* en el Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.comparison.php).

PERO, si quieres, puedes simplificar todo:

```
                  $datos = $data2['TC_Estado_eq'];

                  if($datos = "AC") {
                    echo '<td width=80 class=center><font color="#FF0000">Activo</font></td>';
                  
                  } else{
                    echo '<td width=80 class=center><Font color="#FF8C00">Inactivo</FONT></td>';
                 }
```

Usando un operador ternario que asigne las propiedades en un array:

```
$datos = $data2['TC_Estado_eq'] == 'AC' ? 
             array('txt'=>'Activo', 'color'=>'#FF0000') : 
             array('txt'=>'Inactivo', 'color'=>'#FF8C00') ;

printf('<td width=80 class=center><font color="%s">%s</font></td>',$datos['txt'],$datos['color']);
```

Así el código quedaría más limpio y sería más portable.

Comment: Muchas gracias tenias razon me funciono

Comment: @AlbertoCruz también puedes simplificar con un ternario, revisa la respuesta editada, al final.

Comment: deja lo pruebo como me comentas al final me funciona mejor simplificado